# Remove Facebook Likebox on smaller screen / mobile devices

Tags: facebook, responsive-design, facebook-likebox

Is there a method to not display and important not load the Facebook Likebox on devices with a certain screen size (for example: not on smartphones) or certain data connection (not wifi), the likebox slows down the website significantly.

So the method display:none; is no option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there's no way to (reliably) query for data connection type.

May I suggest a different approach? perhaps you could load the likebox on demand using javascript, the way [techcrunch.com](http://techcrunch.com) or [enter.co](http://enter.co) do it. Those sites load the social buttons only when you hover over some placeholder images.

This way, you optimize not only for mobile screens but for all devices. If you still want, you could check the viewport size before loading the buttons, or use display:none inside a media query so the placeholder images are not shown –and the buttons can't be loaded.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried such an approach for the likebox but faced some problems in IE. I will research it further and post my results here.

Answer (score 1):

Why not a simple echo based on a conditional ?

For connection you would get the users speed perhaps using a bit of code like this: http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2006/05/31/determine-connection-speed-with-php/

Then an if statement if the speed is above say 56k, output the likebox code?

For mobiles, you would do the same after getting the browsers user agent.